# MySQL YEAR Comparison

Tags: mysql

Years ago, I wrote a query and now while going back through some of this old code I'm trying to figure out why I did it the way it had been done. The intent, as far as I can tell, was to simply extract the year from a UNIX timestamp. Can anyone tell me what the benefit might have been to use:

```
YEAR(DATE_ADD(DATE_SUB(DATE_ADD(FROM_UNIXTIME( 0 ), INTERVAL FullDate SECOND), INTERVAL @@session.time_zone HOUR_MINUTE), INTERVAL '08:00' HOUR_MINUTE))
```

Instead of simply:

```
DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(FullDate), '%Y')
```

Comment: This can/has to be used if `FullDate` can be negative (e.g. your date lies before 1970) or after 2038, as `from_unixtime` does not support this. You may want to check the context if that could have been the case.

Comment: The site does use negative years so maybe that's why I went this route, copying it from something I wrote for another area, but in this case all the years are relatively recent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you were trying to compensate for whatever the current time zone was and then output the (year of the) current time in the timezone `UTC+8:00` (countries this applies to from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC%2B08:00)).

So `DATE_ADD(FROM_UNIXTIME( 0 ), INTERVAL FullDate SECOND)` gives you the current time, in the current time zone; the `DATE_SUB(..., INTERVAL @@session.time_zone HOUR_MINUTE)` converts that to UTC, and `DATE_ADD(..., INTERVAL '08:00' HOUR_MINUTE)` then converts the time to `UTC+8:00`.

If you didn't want to make that timezone conversion, then `DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(FullDate), '%Y')` will do the job, as in fact would `FROM_UNIXTIME(FullDate, '%Y')` or `YEAR(FROM_UNIXTIME(FullDate))`

Comment: Thank you! That's exactly what I wanted to know.